# Text decoding in PHP with HTMLEntities and Mandarin?

Tags: php, encoding

I have the following string in an XLF file:

```
&lt;h2&gt;&lt;a href=â€/SOMEURLâ€&gt;å°‹æ‰¾é©åˆæ
```

If I apply html_entity_decode, I end up with:

```
<a href=â€/SOMEURLâ€>å°‹æ‰
```

It correctly dealt with:

```
&lt;  .... <
&gt;  .... >
```

But the problem is with the:

```
â
```

This should be:

```
"
```

So what must I do to get the correctly encoded string back when reading from the file?

**MORE BACKGROUND INFO**

This is how i am converting the XLF file into a PHP array:

```
function website_export_xml_to_array($data) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($data, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);
    $json = json_encode($xml);
    $xmlArray = json_decode($json,TRUE);
    return $xmlArray;
}

$xml = file_get_content("myxmlfile.xlf");
$xml = website_export_xml_to_array($xml);
```

Perhaps something is going wrong at this point already?

Comment: what is an xlf file? Who generates it? How?

Comment: Sounds like the `â€` are smart quotes misencoded.. What generates the XLF?

Comment: And XLF file is XLIFF format... it's a format used to do translations. So it would basically have an "source xml" tag and a "target xml" tag, where the text goes. I'll see if I can't add a full example./

Comment: An app called "Trados" is generating the code.